# Firefox MacOS versions 68 and 69 no longer uses address bar for search, only navigation

Tags: firefox

I set Firefox to install updates automatically and installed one recently. This new version no longer uses the address bar for search, i.e. if I type "some random search", it is trimmed to "some" and redirected to "www.some.com", which is the navigation behavior and not the search behavior.

The keyword searches still work, i.e. "d some random search" where "d" is the keyword for DuckDuckGo web search. Without a search keyword, I expect Firefox to use the default search engine and instead I have the behaviour above.

I checked the settings and Search bar is at "Use the address bar for search and navigation":

[image: Firefox search bar behavior]

If I change it "Add search in toolbar", the behavior of the address bar is the same but the search bar doesn't work either.

My system is macOS 10.14.5; the Firefox version history shows:

```
Firefox 68.0 (20190705220548)
Details
Installed on: 12 July 2019, 11:03:07
Status: The Update was successfully installed
```

I have no add-ons or extensions installed. I believe this is a bug and should affect many people. Has anyone found a fix?

Comment: Verify that the problem isn't an extension.  Restart Firefox in safe mode (you can do that from `about:profiles`, there's a button for "Restart with add-ons disabled").

Comment: Restarting in Safe Mode has none of these problems, and seems to have fixed the problem, as now when I restart normally again the problems are gone.

Comment: @fixer1234 I have no add-ons or extensions installed, by the way.

Comment: All solved, I presume? :)

Comment: @BoffinBrain Yes, and I added an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reported a bug at [BugZilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1565792). I had the problem with versions 68.0 and 69.0, but the bug seemed solved by restarting Firefox, so I was not able to get the details requested from the bug report and the bug report was closed.

I tested again last week when Firefox auto-updated to 70.0.1 and I did not have this behavior, so the problem seems gone for good.